# Save a bitmap to a file has inconsistent results

Tags: android

I'm trying to save a bitmap to a file. The code works OK in one device (Nexus S) but I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException` on a Samsung S 3. Both of them are running Android version 4.1.2. Here's the code I'm using:

```
                File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
                try {
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(file));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Nothing really special about this code. Any ideas why it's not working on the S3? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some deep documentation reading and apparently Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES may not necessarily exist, so we must explicitly check for that:

```
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
                    if(!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
                    }
```